# ExecutionContext does not contain 'FunctionAppDirectory' in Azure Function

Tags: visual-studio, azure, intellisense, azure-functions

I'm passing in ExecutionContext into my Azure Function and I want to pull up the

```
context.FunctionAppDirectory
```

but intellisense doesn't have it. See pic below.
When I debug and step to it, I can see it, but it's not there under intellisense.

[image]

Trying to get FunctionAppDirectory

[image]

Here is the breakpoint in the debugger where I can see it exists.

[image]

I tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding and restarting but none of those worked.

Comment: Which version of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` / `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` are you referencing?

Comment: .Net.Sdk.Functions is 1.0.2 and webjobs.extensions is 2.10-beta 1

Comment: I just upgraded to the latest nuget and that fixed it! thanks

Comment: @user1186050, thank you for sharing your solution, could you please add a reply with your solution and mark it as an answer when you have free time? That will help other community members who meet the same or similar issues to easier search this useful information, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

`FunctionAppDirectory` was introduced in version `1.0.4` of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`, so upgrade your NuGet package dependency.